# Android testing. Mocking HttpUrlConnection(partially)

Tags: android, unit-testing, http, integration-testing, android-testing

I have to create a test system that intercept all HTTP requests but should handle only few, after some researches I found [this](https://gist.github.com/xaethos/3792258) article that shows how to mock HttpUrlConnection but I have to adapt, I want to use this only for requests that is part of my test, the others should go through internet as usualy, my try was to return different HttpUrlConnection objects that depends on url and obviously didn't work.

```
    public class MockURLStreamHandler extends URLStreamHandler implements URLStreamHandlerFactory
{
    ..............................
    // *** URLStreamHandler

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {

        mConnection = new MockHttpURLConnection(u);
        if(u.toString().equals(myTestUrl))
        {
           return mConnection;
         }
        else
        {
          //this doesn't work 
            return new HttpUrlConnection(u){..}
       }  
    }
    ...............................
}
```

Any ideas ? after what I should looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using Mockito?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver)

> This library makes it easy to test that your app Does The Right Thing
>   when it makes HTTP and HTTPS calls. It lets you specify which
>   responses to return and then verify that requests were made as
>   expected.
>
> Because it exercises your full HTTP stack, you can be confident that
>   you're testing everything. You can even copy & paste HTTP responses
>   from your real web server to create representative test cases. Or test
>   that your code survives in awkward-to-reproduce situations like 500
>   errors or slow-loading responses.